# use preg_match to grab value

Tags: php, regex

this is what I have so far:

```
$data = "Hello this is on1";
if (preg_match("/n/", $data)){
  $status = "it contains n";
}
if (preg_match("/n1/", $data)){
  $status1 = "it contains n1";
}
echo $status;
echo $status1;
```

this will say that `$data` it contains "n" then that `$data` contains "n1"
the issue I am having is how do I grab "n" alone. 
it should return "it contains n" only if `$data="Hello this contains n"`;
in other terms the letter "n" should not be attached to ANY number, if it's attached to something else that's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use word boundaries `\b` and negative lookahead like this:

```
if (preg_match("/\b(n(?!\d+)[^\b]*)/", $data)){
  $status = "it contains n";
}
```

`\b` will make sure `n` is matched with word boundaries hence `on1` will not be matched.

Comment: thanks but I specified that the letter should not be followed by a digit

Comment: Oh sorry but this text in your question: `it should return "it contains n" only` says otherwise or may be just my bad interpretation.

Comment: Edited my answer based on your comment.

Comment: @anubhava: `\b` loses its usual meaning when it appears in a character class, so `[^\b]*` matches zero or more of any characters except backspace.  I'm pretty sure that's not what you meant.

Comment: @AlanMoore: That's a very good point, I wasn't aware of that. Thanks for teaching me this important tip.

Answer (score 1):

You could adjust your regex to bypass any combinations of "n" followed by a number like so:

```
/n[^\d]/
```

Note that `\d` stands in for a digit, and the `[^...]` syntax will match anything that *isn't* within the character group.

Comment: isnt ^  mean that it starts with what follows ?

Answer (score 0):

Semi-combination of the other 2 responses:

```
/\bn\D*/
```

- `\b` signifies a word boundary
- `\D` signifies any non-digit character
- `*` signifies 0 or more occurence (of the non-digit chars)

**EDIT:** Thanks to Alan here's a better version:

```
/\bn[^\d\s]*\b/
```

Comment: `\D*` doesn't exclude digits, it merely consumes non-digits if there are any.  To say "not followed by a digit" you need a negative lookahead: `(?!\d)`